# How to stop test execution in Robot Framework through keywords implemented with Java?

Tags: java, keyword, robotframework

I have a keyword implemented with Java and if keyword fails i need to stop the whole test execution with message: "ERROR: example message".

Comment: This is a valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the user guide under [Reporting keyword status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#reporting-keyword-status):

You may throw any exception in the keyword method. The exception type will be used as prefix and you can add a message as well.

Comment: I have not succeeded to implement the solution from user guide, but i've solved the problem with "throw new AssertionError("ERROR: example message");"

Comment: The user guide also says raising Exceptions is the correct way

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

Raising exceptions is the officially recommended way.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#reporting-keyword-status

Java (as there in the comment to accepted answer)

```
throw new AssertionError("ERROR: example message")
```

Python

```
from exceptions import AssertionError
.
.
.
 def rftest(self):
   test_result = lib.runtest()
   if (0 != test_result ):
          raise AssertionError("Test Failed")
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions for this:

- First solution:

In the test itself you can use

```
Library         Dialogs
(....)
pause execution     myMessage
```

which will show a popup on the screen and pause the execution until the OK button is called. 
You can, for instance return a specific value from the java keyword in case of error and pause  if that value is returned.

- Second Solution

I prefer this one: just connect a debugger to the java code which executes the keyword and stop when an exception occurs. It also allows to inspect the state of the JVM at that moment. [This post](http://esalagea.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/remote-debugging-of-robot-framework-integration-test-with-maven/) shows how to do connect a remote debugger to the jvm which runs the robot keyword.